# Python native coroutines and send()

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

Generator based coroutines have a `send()` method which allow bidirectional communication between the caller and the callee and resumes a yielded generator coroutine from the caller. This is the functionality that turns generators into coroutines.

While the new native `async/await` coroutines provide superior support for async I/O, I do not see how to get the equivalent of `send()` with them. The use of `yield` in `async` functions is explicitly forbidden, so native coroutines can return only once using a `return` statement. Although `await` expressions bring new values into a coroutine, those values come from callees, not the caller, and the awaited call is evaluated from the beginning each time, not from where it left off.

Is there a way to resume a returned coroutine from where it left off and potentially send in a new value?
How can I emulate the techniques in David Beazley's [Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) using native coroutines?

The general code pattern I have in mind is something like

```
def myCoroutine():
  ...
  while True:
    ...
    ping = yield(pong)
    ...
```

and in the caller

```
while True:
  ...
  buzz = myCoroutineGen.send(bizz)
  ...
```

---

#### Edit

I accepted Kevin's answer but I have noticed that the PEP [says](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/#coroutine-object-methods)

> Coroutines are based on generators internally, thus they share the implementation. Similarly to generator objects, *coroutines* have `throw()`, `send()` and `close()` methods.

...

> `throw()`, `send()` methods for *coroutines* are used to push values and raise errors into *Future-like* objects.

So apparently native coroutines do have a `send()`? How does it work without `yield` expression to receive the values inside the coroutine?

Comment: It's still not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve by using this code pattern, or why you can't just use `yield from` generator-coroutines instead.

Comment: I wanted to see how to port David Beazley's code that the question links to, but that is not what async/await are meant for.

Comment: @DanielMahler per your updated question: yes, `send` is supported in native coroutines, [see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74786894/1080804)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a way to resume a returned coroutine from where it left off and potentially send in a new value?

No.

`async` and `await` are *just* syntactic sugar for `yield from`.  When a coroutine returns (with the `return` statement), that's it.  The frame is gone.  It is not resumable.  This is exactly how generators have always worked.  For example:

```
def foo():
    return (yield)
```

You can do `f = foo(); next(f); f.send(5)`, and you will get back 5.  But if you try to `f.send()` again, it does not work, because you already returned from the frame.  `f` is no longer a live generator.

Now, as for new coroutines, so far as I can tell, it seems yielding and sending is reserved for communication between the event loop and certain basic predicates such as `asyncio.sleep()`.  The coroutines yield [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future) objects up to the event loop, and the event loop sends those same future objects back into the coroutine once the associated operations have been completed (they are typically scheduled via [`call_soon()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.call_soon) and the other event loop methods).

You can yield future objects by awaiting them, but it's not a general-purpose interface like `.send()` was.  It is specifically intended for use by the event loop implementation.  If you are not implementing an event loop, you probably do not want to be playing around with this.  If you *are* implementing an event loop, you need to ask yourself why the perfectly good implementations in `asyncio` are not sufficient for your purposes and explain what *specifically* you are trying to do before we can help you.

Please note that `yield from` is not deprecated.  If you want coroutines that are not tied to an event loop at all, just use that instead.  `async` and `await` are [specifically designed for asynchronous programming with event loops](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#abstract).  If that is not what you are doing, then `async` and `await` are the wrong tool to begin with.

One more thing:

> The use of `yield` in async functions is explicitly forbidden, so native coroutines can return only once using a `return` statement.

`await` expressions *do* yield control.  `await something()` is entirely analogous to `yield from something()`.  They just changed the name so it would be more intuitive to people not familiar with generators.

---

For those of you who actually are interested in implementing your own event loop, [here's some example code](https://bitbucket.org/NYKevin/nbtparse/src/e1aec5c6b1691d305a94839791b308835cdadaaf/nbtparse/_utils.py?at=optionally-async&fileviewer=file-view-default#_utils.py-85) showing a (very minimal) implementation.  This event loop is extremely stripped down, because it is designed to run certain specially-written coroutines synchronously as if they were normal functions.  It does not provide the full range of support you would expect from a real [BaseEventLoop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop) implementation, and is not safe for use with arbitrary coroutines.

Ordinarily, I would include the code in my answer, rather than linking to it, but there are copyright concerns and it is not critical to the answer itself.

Comment: _The frame is gone. It is not resumable._ Is it correct to call the new feature coroutines then? Historically the ability to save state and resume has been the defining feature of coroutines.

_This is exactly how generators have always worked._ I do not understand. A loop with a `yield` behaves exactly

Comment: @DanielMahler: State does get saved and restored every time you `await`.  It's just that the control ultimately passes back to the event loop, which is code you (usually) did not write.  But `return` has exactly the same meaning in new coroutines as it did in old generator coroutines: tear down the frame.

Comment: Ok, but `yield` is what makes generators tick. My question is really about native coroutines being a complete replacement for generator coroutines, as they are being promoted, but I am not sure they are actually coroutines.

Comment: @DanielMahler: Nobody said they were a complete replacement.  They are [specifically designed for *asynchronous programming*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#abstract), which necessarily means you are yielding up to an event loop rather than arbitrary code.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought I read some propaganda to the effect that generator coroutines were being deprecated, but this makes more sense. I think that the name _coroutines_ is misleading for this though.

Comment: @DanielMahler: Well, the fact is, this (async with event loops) is what people were using generator coroutines for.  That's why it got a whole PEP and brand-new syntax.  Perhaps "coroutine" is overly general, but it's a nice short name that's good enough for everyone who was only using them with event loops.  And it's not like the keyword `async` isn't a bit of a hint about the purpose of these things.

Comment: Yes but the term _coroutine_ has meaning in computer science dating back to the 60's. The problem I was trying to solve was figuring out how to do actual coroutines with async/await. Now I know I am not supposed to.

Answer (score 38):

After going through the same (fantastic, I must say) course on coroutines by Beazley, I asked myself the very same question - how could one adjust the code to work with the native coroutines introduced in Python 3.5?

It turns out it *can* be done with relatively small changes to the code. I will assume the readers are familiar with the course material, and will take the [pyos4.py](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/pyos4.py) version as a base - the first `Scheduler` version that supports "system calls".

> **TIP:** A full runnable example can be found in **Appendix A** at the end.

### Objective

The goal is turn the following coroutine code:

```py
def foo():
    mytid = yield GetTid()  # a "system call"
    for i in xrange(3):
        print "I'm foo", mytid
        yield  # a "trap"
```

... into a native coroutine and still use just as before:

```py
async def foo():
    mytid = await GetTid()  # a "system call"
    for i in range(3):
        print("I'm foo", mytid)
        await ???  # a "trap" (will explain the missing bit later)
```

We want to run it without `asyncio`, as we already have our own event loop that drives the entire process - it's the `Scheduler` class.

### Awaitable objects

Native coroutines do not work right off the bat, the following code results in an error:

```py
async def foo():
    mytid = await GetTid()
    print("I'm foo", mytid)

sched = Scheduler()
sched.new(foo())
sched.mainloop()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    mytid = await GetTid()
TypeError: object GetTid can't be used in 'await' expression
```

[PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) explains what kind of objects can be awaited on. One of the options is *"an object with an `__await__` method returning an iterator"*.

Just like `yield from`, if you are familiar with it, `await` acts as a tunnel between the object awaited on and the outermost code that drives the coroutine (usually an event loop). This is best demonstrated with an example:

```py
class Awaitable:
    def __await__(self):
        value = yield 1
        print("Awaitable received:", value)
        value = yield 2
        print("Awaitable received:", value)
        value = yield 3
        print("Awaitable received:", value)
        return 42


async def foo():
    print("foo start")
    result = await Awaitable()
    print("foo received result:", result)
    print("foo end")
```

Driving the `foo()` coroutine interactively produces the following:

```py
>>> f_coro = foo()  # calling foo() returns a coroutine object
>>> f_coro
<coroutine object foo at 0x7fa7f74046d0>
>>> f_coro.send(None)
foo start
1
>>> f_coro.send("one")
Awaitable received: one
2
>>> f_coro.send("two")
Awaitable received: two
3
>>> f_coro.send("three")
Awaitable received: three
foo received result: 42
foo end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Whatever gets sent into `f_coro` is channeled down into the `Awaitable` instance. Similarly, whatever `Awaitable.__await__()` produces is bubbled up to the topmost code that sends the values in.

The entire process is transparent to the `f_coro` coroutine, which is not directly involved and does not see values being passed up and down. However, when `Awaitable`'s iterator is exhausted, its **return** value becomes the result of the `await` expression (42 in our case), and that's where `f_coro` is finally resumed.

Note that `await` expressions in coroutines can also be chained. A coroutine can await another coroutine that awaits another coroutine... until the entire chain ends with a `yield` somewhere down the road.

### Sending values into the coroutine itself

How can this knowledge help us? Well, in the course material a coroutine can yield a `SystemCall` instance. The scheduler understands these and lets the system call handle the requested operation.

In order for a coroutine to bring a `SystemCall` up to the scheduler, a `SystemCall` instance can simply *yield itself*, and it will be channeled up to the scheduler as described in the previous section.

The first required change is therefore to add this logic to the base `SystemCall` class:

```py
class SystemCall:
    ...
    def __await__(self):
        yield self
```

With the `SystemCall` instances made awaitable, the following now actually runs:

```py
async def foo():
    mytid = await GetTid()
    print("I'm foo", mytid)

>>> sched = Scheduler()
>>> sched.new(foo())
>>> sched.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```
I'm foo None
Task 1 terminated
```

Great, it does not crash anymore!

However, the coroutine did not receive the task ID, and got `None` instead. This is because the value set by the system call's `handle()` method and sent by the `Task.run()` method:

```py
# in Task.run()
self.target.send(self.sendval)
```

... ended up in the `SystemCall.__await__()` method. If we want to bring the value into the coroutine, the system call must **return** it, so that it becomes the value of the `await` expression in the coroutine.

```py
class SystemCall:
    ...
    def __await__(self):
        return (yield self)
```

Running the same code with the modified `SystemCall` produces the desired output:

```
I'm foo 1
Task 1 terminated
```

### Running the coroutines concurrently

We still need a way to suspend a coroutine, i.e. to have a system "trap" code. In the course material, this is done with a plain `yield` inside a coroutine, but an attempt to use a plain `await` is actually a syntax error:

```py
async def foo():
    mytid = await GetTid()
    for i in range(3):
        print("I'm foo", mytid)
        await  # SyntaxError here
```

Fortunately, the workaround is easy. Since we already have working system calls, we can add a dummy no-op system call whose only job is to suspend the coroutine and immediately re-schedule it:

```py
class YieldControl(SystemCall):
    def handle(self):
        self.task.sendval = None   # setting sendval is optional
        self.sched.schedule(self.task)
```

Setting a `sendval` on the task is optional, as this system call is not expected to produce any meaningful value, but we opt to make this explicit.

We now have everything in place to run a multitasking operating system!

```py
async def foo():
    mytid = await GetTid()
    for i in range(3):
        print("I'm foo", mytid)
        await YieldControl()


async def bar():
    mytid = await GetTid()
    for i in range(5):
        print("I'm bar", mytid)
        await YieldControl()


sched = Scheduler()
sched.new(foo())
sched.new(bar())
sched.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```
I'm foo 1
I'm bar 2
I'm foo 1
I'm bar 2
I'm foo 1
I'm bar 2
Task 1 terminated
I'm bar 2
I'm bar 2
Task 2 terminated
```

### Footnotes

#### The `Scheduler` code is completely unchanged.

It. Just. Works.

This shows the beauty of the original design where the scheduler and the tasks that run in it are not coupled to each other, and we were able to change the coroutine implementation without the `Scheduler` knowing about it. Even the `Task` class that wraps the coroutines did not have to change.

#### Trampolining is not needed.

In the [pyos8.py](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/pyos8.py) version of the system, a concept of a *trampoline* is implemented. It allows the coroutines to delegate a part of their work to another coroutine with the help of the shceduler (the scheduler calls the sub-coroutine on behalf of the parent coroutine and sends the former's result into the parent).

This mechanism is not needed, since `await` (and its older companion, `yield from`) already make such chaining possible as explained at the beginning.

### Appendix A - a full runnable example (requires Python 3.5+)

example_full.py

```py
from queue import Queue


# ------------------------------------------------------------
#                       === Tasks ===
# ------------------------------------------------------------
class Task:
    taskid = 0
    def __init__(self,target):
        Task.taskid += 1
        self.tid = Task.taskid   # Task ID
        self.target = target        # Target coroutine
        self.sendval = None          # Value to send

    # Run a task until it hits the next yield statement
    def run(self):
        return self.target.send(self.sendval)


# ------------------------------------------------------------
#                      === Scheduler ===
# ------------------------------------------------------------
class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = Queue()   
        self.taskmap = {}        

    def new(self,target):
        newtask = Task(target)
        self.taskmap[newtask.tid] = newtask
        self.schedule(newtask)
        return newtask.tid

    def exit(self,task):
        print("Task %d terminated" % task.tid)
        del self.taskmap[task.tid]

    def schedule(self,task):
        self.ready.put(task)

    def mainloop(self):
         while self.taskmap:
            task = self.ready.get()
            try:
                result = task.run()
                if isinstance(result,SystemCall):
                    result.task  = task
                    result.sched = self
                    result.handle()
                    continue
            except StopIteration:
                self.exit(task)
                continue
            self.schedule(task)


# ------------------------------------------------------------
#                   === System Calls ===
# ------------------------------------------------------------
class SystemCall:
    def handle(self):
        pass

    def __await__(self):
        return (yield self)


# Return a task's ID number
class GetTid(SystemCall):
    def handle(self):
        self.task.sendval = self.task.tid
        self.sched.schedule(self.task)


class YieldControl(SystemCall):
    def handle(self):
        self.task.sendval = None   # setting sendval is optional
        self.sched.schedule(self.task)


# ------------------------------------------------------------
#                      === Example ===
# ------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def foo():
        mytid = await GetTid()
        for i in range(3):
            print("I'm foo", mytid)
            await YieldControl()


    async def bar():
        mytid = await GetTid()
        for i in range(5):
            print("I'm bar", mytid)
            await YieldControl()

    sched = Scheduler()
    sched.new(foo())
    sched.new(bar())
    sched.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answers actually answers the questions and should have more points

Comment: thank you for recommending Beazleys coroutine course - it's phantastic! And thank you for taking time to explain the adaptions needed for async/await! I must say my head just exploded, but I hope I learned some things along the way :)

Comment: Initially, my head exploded, too (which is why we love Dave's courses), but once you understand the idea, it becomes a new powerful addition to the personal programming toolbox. :)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a very old thread. Meanwhile, there is PEP525 (https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/) and an Implementation of asynchronous generators is available. I had the same question and it was difficult to find answers. Therefore my contribution:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def gen():
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            value = yield 'hello'
            print("got:", value) 
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        yield 'world'


async def main():
    now = time.time()
    g = gen()
    v = await g.asend(None)
    v = await g.asend('something')
    b = await g.asend(None)
    c = await g.asend(None)
    print(v,b,c, time.time() - now) 

    v = await g.athrow(ZeroDivisionError)
    print(v)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This answers the __updated__ question from the OP: "So apparently native coroutines do have `send()`? *AND* this is extremely clean code, thank you for highlighting this under-documented feature!