# How to simplify python coroutines?

Tags: python-3.x, coroutine, synchronous

I really would like to use python coroutines to simplify my data consumers, but I find the standard implementation not very elegant:

```
def printer():
    print('setup')

    try:
        while True:
            data = yield
            print(data)

    except GeneratorExit:
        pass

    print('cleanup')
```

Is there a way to write a consumer by using a for loop?

```
def printer():
    print('setup')

    for data in yield_iterator():
        print(data)

    print('cleanup')
```

I tried a few different things to encapsulate `yield` and the handling of `GeneratorExit`, but as soon as I move `yield` into a sub-function `printer()` isn't recognized as a coroutine anymore.

Do you know of an elegant way to write coroutines in python?

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to build a solution based on the answer from [plamut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5040035/plamut):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118660/11462250

The key was to create an awaitable object that *yields* in *await*

```
class Awaitable:
    def __await__(self):
        return (yield)
```

Then it's possible to write something like this:

```
async def printer(source):
    print('setup')

    async for data in source:
        print(data)

    print('cleanup')
```